# if and or statements with strings

Tags: python, string, if-statement

I have these variables, a, b, c, and d. They are length 75 lists of values, however some of the values are the string 'n/a'. In order to do any calculations with these values, I need to filter out the 'n/a's.

Here is my code:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if str(a)!='n/a' & str(b)!='n/a' & str(c)!='n/a' & str(d)!='n/a': #problem area
        a*b/c*d #some function here.
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `&` is bitwise I suppose

Comment: use `and` instead of `&`. `and` is logical which you need.

Comment: Try typing *and operator python* into google, and see what you get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&` is a bitwise operator, and should only be used on integers. Try using `and` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Replace these `&`'s with `and` or use braces for operator precedence as:

```
if (str(a)!='n/a') & (str(b)!='n/a') & (str(c)!='n/a') & (str(d)!='n/a'):
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your condition with `if 'n/a' not in map(str, [a,b,c,d]):`

Answer (score 0):

```
for w, x, y, z in zip(a, b, c, d):
    try:
        result = w * x / y * z
        # now do something with result
    except TypeError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner that is still kind of readable:

```
a,b,c,d = zip(*[row for row in zip(a,b,c,d) if "n/a" not in row])
```